# Laplace transform initial conditions

Tags: python, sympy

How to define initial conditions for Laplace transform in Sympy? 
For example:

```
t,s = symbols('t s')
x = Function('x')(t)
laplace_transform(diff(x,t),t,s cond=(x(0) = 1))
```

So the output would be:

```
s*L(x) - 1
```

Comment: Shouldn't the result be `s -> s * X(s) - 1` instead of `s -> X(s) - 1`? I am using `X` as an equivalent of your `L(x)`

Comment: When I am checking the [doc](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/integrals/integrals.html#sympy.integrals.transforms.laplace_transform), it seems you have to pass a "concrete" function expression. Example: `laplace_transform(t**a, t, s)` hence, defining initial condition becomes useless (as they are self contained in the function expression itself). It feels like you want to use Laplace properties on derivatives (independently of the function definition), I don't think this library allows you to do so. But I just checked quickly :)

Comment: @MarAja nope, you should multiply by s for every derivative. At least that's how I was taught. You could try to calculate an integral to prove the point.

Comment: @MarAja That's what I saw too. I think it's not too complicated to implement that that's why I think it could be done somehow.

Comment: In your example, `diff(x, t)` is the derivative of the `x` function along the `t` variable, right? So the result should indeed be multiplied by `s` which does not appear in your initial post, am I wrong?

Comment: @MarAja yes, sorry. I misunderstood you. Thanks.

Comment: @UpmostScarab Does every function `x(t)` has a Laplace transform? If not, then the output you request is not correct (in general).

Comment: @Stelios I agree but in model tasks we assume that the function has a Laplace transform.

Comment: @UpmostScarab `Sympy` does not know that your considered `x(t)` is "well-behaved" and I do not think that, currently, there is an option to inform `Sympy` that this is the case. Hopefully this option appears in a future version.

Comment: @Stelios  thank you for  a. confident answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Laplace transforms of undefined functions are not yet implemented. There is an [issue](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7219) tracking this. Perhaps the simple [workaround implementation](https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues/7219#issuecomment-154768904) in that issue will work for you for now.